# Three phase induction motor

Tags: motor, magnetic-flux

If speed of rotating flux and actual speed of rotor is same then what will be the torque produced in three phase induction motor and why?

Comment: A quick answer: the torque will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

If the rotor's frequency matches that of the stator (assuming polecount has already been considered) there will be no torque produced.

Induction machines are also referred to as asynchronous machines

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the rotor and the field are rotating at the same speed then how much actual induction is occurring (How often does the rotor cut a line of flux from the windings)?

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as an answer. If it is a hint it's a bit obscure and should be converted to a comment.

Comment: I didn't think it was that obscure as a hint, I mean the guy is clearly studying electrical machines and electromagnetism, so the words should have meaning? What I did not want to do was just answer a clearly homework question, there is no learning in that. I would not however be adverse to converting to a comment, as I initially thought I was going to write rather more, but could not come up with a more verbose way to point to a solution without actually giving it.